# Heroku cant use gamedig node module

Tags: heroku

Heroku isn't letting me use gamedig. It's telling me that gamedig isnt installed, I tried uninstalling and installing gamedig but nothing is working. Gamedig works locally.

Comment: Can you please explain "nothing is working" in detail? E.g. what is not working and maybe you also have a error message for us.

Comment: Check the heroku server logs via `heroku logs -n 1000` and see if you can't find the error message.